# Javascript external function with event handler to generate DOM elements is not outputting html

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, dom-events

I am trying to dynamically generate and remove input boxes based on selection. However, I have been tweaking this code for hours but can't figure out why it's not generating the html elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title> Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css." type="text/css"
<script src="js/addInputs.js"></script>
<script>
            
        function addListeners() {
            if (window.addEventListener) {
                document.getElementById('sel_value').addEventListener("change", yourSelection, false);
            }

            function youSelection() {
                // create three inputs with three labels fro array
                if (document.getElementById('sel_value').value == 1) { addInputs(4,panel01);}           
            
                            // create six inputs with six labels from array
            else if (document.getElementById('sel_value').value == 2) { addInputs(6,panel02);} 
                
                else {
                               //clear panel 1
                var remove_p01 = document.getElementById('panel01');
                        remove_p01.parentNode.removeChild(remove_p01);
        
                          // clear panel 2
                    var remove_p02 = document.getElementById('panel02');
                    remove_p02.parentNode.removeChild(remove_p02);                   
                }
                
                
            }
        }

        window.onload = addListeners;
    </script></head><body>
  
 // HTML Code
<div id="container">
    <label for="addinputs">No. of Ports</label><!-- lablel for selector--->
    <input id="sel_value" type="number" min="0" max="3" /><br />

</div></div></body></html>
```

// External Javascript File

```
function addInputs(num_of_inputs, div_id) {
    "use strict";

    var main_container, div, fieldLabel, input, count, label_array;    
    
             // Labels for input fields
    label_array = ["Name", "Height", "Width", "Depth", "Position x", "Position Y"];

              // main container id
    main_container.document.getElementById('container');
              // this div is to hold the input fields 
    div.document.createElement('div');
    div.id = div_id; 
    
           // create labels and inputs
    while (count < num_of_inputs) {

        fieldLabel.createElement('input');
        fieldLabel.type = "text";
        fieldLabel.value = label_array[count];
        fieldLabel.id = "r-port_label" + count;


        input.document.createElement('input');
        input.type = "number";
        input.value = "0";
        input.id = "r_port_input" + count;

        // attach inputs and labels to parent div
        div.appendChild(fieldLabel);
        div.appendChild(input);
        
        //increment input fields & labels
        count += 1; 


    }

    // attach parent div to page container
    main_container.appendChild(div);
}
```

//CSS Code

```
#container{
width: 400px; min-height: 400px; background: #eeeeee;


}
```

Comment: This `main_container.document.getElementById('container');` should be `main_container = document.getElementById('container');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow this look like a disaster. You have like 1000 errors, it looks like somebody delibretly scramble code. Anyhow there you go code that will do something, you adjust it how you wish.

You have:

- wrong function calling in your listener
- missing quotes when you passing ID of panels
- not initialized counter
- false element creation

luckily you have "user strict" :o)

```js
function addInputs(num_of_inputs, div_id) {
 "use strict";
 var main_container, div, fieldLabel, input, count, label_array;    

 // Labels for input fields
 label_array = ["Name", "Height", "Width", "Depth", "Position x", "Position Y"];

 // main container id
 main_container = document.getElementById('container');
 // this div is to hold the input fields 
 div = document.createElement('div');
 div.id = div_id; 

    // create labels and inputs
    count = 0;
 while (count < num_of_inputs) {
  fieldLabel = document.createElement('input');
  fieldLabel.type = "text";
  fieldLabel.value = label_array[count];
  fieldLabel.id = "r-port_label" + count;


  input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "number";
  input.value = "0";
  input.id = "r_port_input" + count;

  // attach inputs and labels to parent div
  div.appendChild(fieldLabel);
  div.appendChild(input);

  //increment input fields & labels
  count += 1; 
 } 

 // attach parent div to page container
 main_container.appendChild(div);
}        

function addListeners() {
 if (window.addEventListener) {
  document.getElementById('sel_value').addEventListener("change", 
  function (){
   // create three inputs with three labels fro array
   if (document.getElementById('sel_value').value == 1) { addInputs(4,'panel01');}           

   // create six inputs with six labels from array
   else if (document.getElementById('sel_value').value == 2) { addInputs(6,'panel02');} 

   else {
    //clear panel 1
    var remove_p01 = document.getElementById('panel01');
    remove_p01.parentNode.removeChild(remove_p01);

    // clear panel 2
    var remove_p02 = document.getElementById('panel02');
    remove_p02.parentNode.removeChild(remove_p02);                   
   }    
  }
  , false);
 }
}
window.onload = addListeners;
```

```css
#container{
 width: 400px; min-height: 400px; background: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <label for="addinputs">No. of Ports</label><!-- lablel for selector--->
  <input id="sel_value" type="number" min="0" max="3" /><br />
</div>
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo, should'nt this:

```
main_container.document.getElementById('container');

div.document.createElement('div');

fieldLabel.createElement('input');

input.document.createElement('input');
```

be:

```
main_container = document.getElementById('container');

div = document.createElement('div');

fieldLabel = document.createElement('input');

input = document.createElement('input');
```